# Determining distribution followed by Create Random Points tool of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, random

I have created a random sample in ArcGIS using the [Create Random Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm) tool. I know that the tool generates a pseudo-random number generator and in my case is ACM599 with seed number 0(default).

How can I know which distribution it follows?

Comment: This from the tool help....The first step of processing is to create a random number stream from a random number generator and seed. When generating random points within a specified extent, a random value on the x-axis and another on the y-axis of the extent are identified, which become the x- and y- coordinates for a point. To randomly select the point on the x-axis, the next unused value on the random number stream is selected and transformed into a Uniform distribution with a minimum and maximum being the minimum and maximum for the x extent. The same is done for the y-axis.